# keep dynamically added elements after postback

Tags: jquery-ui, dynamic, tabs, postback

i got a big problem with jquery and the postback.

i'm dynamically adding html elements to my page. e.g. JQuery UI Tabs.

but after postback ALL dynamically added elements are gone.

how can i keep all of these elements after postback and also the values of textboxes and datetimepicker?

greetz

Tobi

EDIT:

e.g. i'm adding some JqueryUI Tabs with this code:

```
$(function () {
                var $tab_title_input = $("#tab_title"),
            $tab_content_input = $("#tab_content");
                var tab_counter = 1;

                var $addButton = $('<li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top add-button"><span>+</span></li>');
                $addButton.click(function () { addTab(); });


                var $tabs = $("#tabsTravel, #tabsWork").tabs({ autoHeight: true, fillSpace: true,
                    tabTemplate: "<li><a href='#{href}'>#{label}</a> <span class='ui-icon ui-icon-close'>Remove Tab</span></li>",
                    add: function (event, ui) {
                        var tab_content = $tab_content_input.val() || "Tab " + tab_counter + " content.";
                        $(ui.panel).append("<p>" + tab_content + "</p>");

                        $("#tabsTravel ul.ui-tabs-nav").append($addButton);
                    }
                });

                $("#tabsTravel ul.ui-tabs-nav").append($addButton);

                // actual addTab function
                function addTab() {
                    tab_counter++;
                    var tab_title = "worker " + tab_counter;
                    $tabs.tabs("add", "#tabsTravel-" + tab_counter, tab_title)
                 .tabs("select", "#tabsWork-" + tab_counter, tab_title);

                }

                // close icon: removing the tab on click
                $("#tabsTravel span.ui-icon-close").live("click", function () {
                    var index = $("li", $tabs).index($(this).parent());
                    $tabs.tabs("remove", index);
                    tab_counter--;
                });
                $("#tabsWork span.ui-icon-close").live("click", function () {
                    var index = $("li", $tabs).index($(this).parent());
                    $tabs.tabs("remove", index);
                    //                    tab_counter--;
                });
                $('#button').click(function () {
                    addTab()
                });
            });
```

how can i implement this localStorage to this code?

greetz

Bl!tz

Answer (score 0):

Normally this would be the job of your server-side code; you would save the added elements in  the the session cache, or in the database if the changes need to be permanent.

You could also consider using the new HTML5 *session storage*, or *local storage*, but this approach will probably be more of a hassle; best to use the sophisticated server-side libraries of PHP, .NET, etc, if possible.

*Edit*

Here's a simple example.  Let's say your client script adds some HTML to the page:

```
var html = "<div>hello world</div>";
$("body").append(html);
```

Now, you can save it in local storage like this:

```
localStorage.setItem("dynamichtml", html);
```

If you put something in your page startup script like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (localStorage["dynamichtml"]) {
        $("body").append(localStorage["dynamichtml"]);
    }
});
```

Then you will have achieved the dynamic functionality.  Note that the *localStorage* data will remain saved until the user deletes it explicitly.

Comment: and how can i get this to work? i'm writing my code with VS 2010 and my codebehind in c#. could you give me an example?

Comment: @user1414157 A bit hard to say when you haven't told me what your back-end platform is :)

Comment: @user1414157 I just added an example using *localStorage*.